# Unable to read data from serial port in C on Ubuntu

Tags: c, serialization

I have two C Programs 1. To Write Data to Serial Port and 2. To Read Data from Serial Port. I have connected a USB-Serial converter to my laptop and shorted Tx & Rx to test the program.
Program 1 is getting executed successfully.
Program 2 blocks at read.

Can anyone please suggest a solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Program to Write to Serial Port:

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */

/*
 * 'open_port()' - Open serial port 1.
 *
 * Returns the file descriptor on success or -1 on error.
 */
int write_port(void)
{
  int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */

  fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
  if (fd == -1)
  {
   /* Could not open the port. */
    perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyUSB0 - ");
  }
  else
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

  int n = write(fd, "ATZ\r", 4);
  if (n < 0)
    fputs("write() of 4 bytes failed!\n", stderr);

  return (fd);
}

void main(){
    printf("\nAccessing Serial Port to Write\n");
    int fd=write_port();
    if(fd<0){
        printf("\nSerial Port Access Failed\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("\n%d\tSuccess\n",fd);
}
```

Program to Read from Serial Port:

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */

/*
 * 'read_port()' - Reads serial port 1.
 *
 * Returns the file descriptor on success or -1 on error.
 */
int read_port(void)
{
    int fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        /* Could not open the port. */
        perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyUSB0 - ");
    }

    char buffer[32];

    int n = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (n < 0)
        fputs("read failed!\n", stderr);
    return (fd);
}

void main(){
        printf("\nAccessing Serial Port to Read\n");
    int fd=read_port();
    if(fd<0){
        printf("\nSerial Port Access Failed\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("\n%d\tSuccess\n",fd);
}
```

Comment: You're only sending 4 bytes but your read call is waiting to receive 32 bytes.

Comment: Your `read_port` function opens the device, but never closes it. It also attempts to read form the descriptor even if the `open` call failed. And it returns the descriptor no matter how the `read` call went.

Comment: Couple of things. Are you running the reader before the writer? Running the writer first will simply result in the bytes being sent without waiting for the reader. Also the writer is opening the port with O_RDWR. It would be better if it used O_WRONLY. I'm not convinced that you can open a serial port twice for reading. It is not a regular file, so something wierd might be going on there.

Comment: P.s. I recommend taking a glance at the source code for minicom; that covers just about everything you can imagine regarding handling serial ports in C on a *nix platform. Also I'd be wary of your USB device; there's a lot of very cheap and nasty knockoffs; its worth testing it in some other software if you haven't done so already. I've had endless trouble with them under Linux, especially when it comes to using the hardware flow control lines. Getting genuine FTDI parts or similar is highly recommended for full reliability.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, the program is working fine. The problem is with the USB to Serial Converter the Rx is not working. Issue resolved by replacing the converter.